# Is $y(x)=0$ a solution to the differential equation, $y=y'$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives, exponential-function

I think I read or was told that the natural exponential function, $e^x$ is the only solution to $y=y'$, and that it originally was defined by that property.

But isn't $y(x)=0$ one too?
If so, $e^x$ isn't unique with that property, though $y(x)=0$ obviously isn't a very interesting function.

Have I been misinformed or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Actually $ce^x$ is the only solution to the equation. So $y(x)=0$ is indeed included when $c=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you read was probably that $e^x$ is the only solution of $y'=y$ such that $y(0)=1$. Actually the set  of all solutions of that differential equation is $\{ce^x\mid c\in\Bbb R\}$. Take $c=0$, and you'll get the null function.

Comment: Ah thanks, that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

actually, you are right but misinformed also, actual complete set of functions with the property $y = y'$ is $y = ke^x$ for all $k \in R$